# php function/code to click a link on local webpage

Tags: php, curl

Can any one simply guide me which php function can i use to click the links on my local webpage.
or
any help how can i accomplish the task.

I need the basic idea to get going.
I want to write a Tiny Autof surf script.

Comment: possibly cUrl will work, but if the site requires JS then you are out of luck.

Comment: I have a basic script written in js. but i want to do it php

Comment: As i said, you can look at phps curl http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php but you will have to handle cookies etc, and if the site requires js, you have problems. Perhaps you can install a headless browser on your server, such as phantom js